# PHP Image Gallery not working with Capital JPG extension in

Tags: php, jpeg, thumbnails

PHP image Gallery not working with Capital JPG extension, it shows an error -- 'Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 23040 bytes)'-- But the other all images are working fine. I am using Uber gallery

I think this part of code affects..

```
 $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);

    // Create new thumbnail
    if ($imgInfo[2] == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
        imagecopyresampled($newImage, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $width, $height);
        imagejpeg($newImage, $destination, $quality);
    } elseif ($imgInfo[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
        imagecopyresampled($newImage, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $width, $height);
        imagegif($newImage, $destination);
    } elseif ($imgInfo[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
        imagecopyresampled($newImage, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $width, $height);
        imagepng($newImage, $destination);
    }

    // Return relative path to thumbnail
    $relativePath = $this->_rThumbsDir . '/' . $fileName;
    return $relativePath;
}
```

How can I fix this issue.